# Adding a Line Between \begin{enumerate} and \item in AUCTeX

Tags: spacing, enumerate, auctex

I am using Emacs with AUCTeX as my editor.  Right now, if I use <kbd>C-c C-e</kbd> and create an `enumerate` environment, it will give me

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \item
\end{enmerate}
```

What I'd like is

```
\begin{enumerate}

  \item

\end{enumerate}
```

Or, at least

```
\begin{enumerate}

  \item
\end{enumerate}
```

That is a single newline between the begin and the first item.  I would like this to work with all environments with items.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably not the most efficient way, but it should do the job:

```lisp
(defun TeX-arg-item-with-newline (_optional)
  "Insert \\item with a newline above and below the macro.
OPTIONAL is ignored."
  (when (or TeX-arg-item-label-p
            (string-equal (LaTeX-current-environment)
                          "description"))
    (let ((TeX-arg-opening-brace LaTeX-optop)
          (TeX-arg-closing-brace LaTeX-optcl))
      (TeX-argument-insert (TeX-read-string
                            (TeX-argument-prompt t nil "Item label"))
                           t)))
  (insert " ")
  (save-excursion
    (re-search-backward "\\\\item"
                        (line-beginning-position) t)
    (forward-line -1)
    (unless (looking-at-p "^[ ]*$")
      (forward-line)
      (LaTeX-newline)
      (indent-according-to-mode)))
  (save-excursion
    (forward-line)
    (unless (looking-at-p "^[ ]*$")
      (LaTeX-newline)
      (delete-horizontal-space))))

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (TeX-add-symbols '("item" TeX-arg-item-with-newline ignore))))
```